# navigation no longer working in phonegap iOs app after updating jqtouch

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, jqtouch

I created an iOS app last year using html, css, js, jqtouch and phonegap. The app has worked well until recently. It appears that since the iOS 5 update, there is a problem with the navigation.

If you scroll down the apps "pages" and try to select any options below the original screen horizon, the navigation doesn't work. Scroll back all the way to the top of the page and the links above the screen horizon all work. If you scroll back up the page, but not all the way to the original starting position, even the links that are above the original screen horizon won't work.

I worked with Phonegap support and they suggested the problem was with jqtouch. I updated the jqtouch files in the project, and now when I try to run the app (from Xcode) in the iPhone simulator or on a test device, the navigation doesn't work at all. Before, the "links/buttons" would change color as they were supposed to but no work. Now, the "links/buttons" won't change color or navigate to the next div or page.

Could someone tell me what I may have missed in updating the jqtouch/jquery files that could cause this?

Comment: Please refrain from adding greetings/salutations/signatures to posts.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and e solve it updaing to the latest jquery and jqtouch version.

Hopefully this will help you.